# Error al generar un APK

Tags: android, gradle

Al compilar no tengo ningun error, pero al generar un `APK`me presenta los siguientes eerores:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

¿Qué debo hacer para resolver los errores indicados?

---

Java version:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo solicitado Error404.

---

Actualmente mi fichero gradle, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7   //these two lines
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7   //are the only ones that matter


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pe.com.demo.swapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'org.junit:junit4-runner:5.0.0-ALPHA'
}
```

Aún me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Error:1 error; aborting
```

---

Fichero gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pe.com.demo.swdinetapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu fichero gradle?

Comment: ¿Que versión de Java tienes en tu ordenador?

Comment: Tengo dos versiones: Java 7 y Java 8.

Comment: Como supongo que estarás utilizando Windows, pon `java -version` para en la consola para saber que versión de Java estás utilizando con tu equipo.

Comment: Java version "1.8.0_111"

Comment: Ahí dice la solución: agrega targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

Comment: Actualiza tu jdk a ver si te funciona 

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente usa Java 8.

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8   
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Cambia estas dos líneas las veces que aparezca.

---

Otra solución que te podría funcionar es, poner la siguiente línea al principio del fichero del `gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Comment: o que las remueva